# how to implement LANG (i18n) prefix in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

In my previous projects, I utilized **vue-i18n**. However, in my most recent project, I've implemented a simpler solution of my own. Now, I find myself needing to add a language prefix to my routes (a new feature), and I'm unsure how to proceed. Resorting back to vue-i18n solely for this purpose is my last resort.

To clarify what I mean by a language prefix, consider these examples:

- ***/en/gallery***
- ***/cs/gallery***

And so on.

An additional aspect that adds complexity is that the current routing should still function as is. Meaning, accessing ***/gallery*** should direct users to a page in their selected language or to the default language page (for example, ***/en/gallery***).

Does anyone have any experience with accomplishing this in **vue-router 4**? I'll continue investigating this issue, but if anyone has already tackled this problem, I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with making global "LangWrap" and making other routes it's children :/